# Change TreeItem height when it resized

Tags: javafx-2

I would like to create TreeView with only vertical scrollbar, so if I decrease window  width content should be wrapped and TreeView should increase their height.

My idea is to make FlowPane - TreeItem as a child.

I try this code, in very different combination

```
FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();        
flowPane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
flowPane.setPrefWidth(200.0f);
flowPane.setMinWidth(100.0f);
flowPane.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
flowPane.getChildren().addAll( /* add many childs which should be wrapped */ );
TreeItem<FlowPane > = new TreeItem<FlowPane>(flowPane);
```

when I decrease width, child elements in FlowPane are wrapped but container doesn't increase height. It looks squeezed.

Any ideas how solve it?

How to make TreeItem which wrapped content and increase height when resized ?

**UPDATE:**
I solve it by add listener to scene

```
scene.widthProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number arg1,    Number arg2) {
           MainController.handleOnResize();
        }
    });
```

Then I iterate through ListView and update height if ListItem has FlowPane as value

```
if (treeItem.getValue() instanceof FlowPane) {
final FlowPane flowPane = (FlowPane) treeItem.getValue();

                    Task task = new Task<Void>() {

                        @Override
                        public Void call() {
                            int i = 0;
                            while (flowPane.getHeight() == 0.0) {
                                if (++i > 2) {
                                    return null;
                                }

                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(500);
                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                }

                            }
                            flowPane.setPrefHeight(flowPane.getHeight() + flowPane.getChildren().size() * 0.95);

                            return null;
                        }
                    };


                    new Thread(task).start();
```

But there is one bug. Occasionally flowPane.getHeight() return wrong value - smaller than excepted

Comment: Maybe the wrong size is associated with the scrollbars occupying some height. Try disabling Horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: post it as an answer then,